# How to add "Read More" in text displayed on several lines but only a certain number of lines with twig

Tags: twig, truncate, twig-filter

I am using the following function in twig to show a part of the content of the description of a news item saved in a database:

```
{{ new.description|striptags|truncate(300,true)|raw|nl2br }}
```

With this function inside a `p` element in the html, I get the text whose characters do not exceed 300 and then I add "Read More" with an element `a`:

```
<p >{{  new.description|striptags|truncate(200,true)|raw|nl2br }}
  <a class="href_blue" href="{{ path('new', {'id': new.id}) }}">
  <strong> [Read More] </strong></a>
</p>
```

This code works for text that comes in a paragraph with more than 300 characters, but if for example I have another one with several "p" elements that are then changed in twig to 
 elements and I need it to only show me several lines because I have A maximum elevation of the container where it is displayed, I would not know how to do it, since it shows me all line breaks until it does not exceed 300 characters.

To clarify it a little more, I show an image of the result:
[image]

What I need is that in the case of Title2 having many line breaks, just show some and add the "Read More" before so that the height of the div is equal to the previous one (to show the example I removed the max- Height and overflow: hidden).

How could I get that?

I greet your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have a for loop to tell you when a new item will have a new set of `<p>` tags? If so, can you fill us in on that particular code?

Comment: Hello @AlvinBunk, the loop I use is very simple, I just get the title and description of the news from the database (the description is saved previously by Tinymce editor, so the content is saved in html). What I need is some way for `truncate` in Twig to consider each line break as a number of characters (which may include a full line in the container), so a long description will never be shown. I do not know if I'm explaining well.

Comment: I wasn't able to find truncate twig documentation. Maybe slice replaces it. You could use [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) to increment a variable based on the number of characters and/or <p> tags you encounter.

Comment: Just that I tried @AlvinBunk, but with "<br>" tags that are contained by the content once transformed with the "raw" filter, because I did not know how to divide by tags <p> which also contains </ p>. Anyway I could not get a solution. I did not get to add the content to the variable and then use it in the condition, something I did wrong. Now I will try it again, but if you could help me a bit with the code I would appreciate it.

Comment: Joseph, if my answer 'worked' as a solution, please mark it with a checkmark to indicate it is the correct answer, unless it only just helped.

Comment: It is still not correct @AlvinBunk, but it goes that way, I have indicated in what I think it must do to get the solution, which is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in Twig:

```
{% set paragraphs = new.description|split('</p>') %}
{% set summary = '' %}
{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {% set summary = summary ~ paragraphs[i] %}
{% endfor %}

{% set summary = summary ~ '[Read More]' %}
```

Now you can use the `summary` variable in your twig file to show the truncated summary.

**EDIT #2 based on comments**

Then try this instead:

```
{% set paragraphs = new.description|split('</p>') %}
{% set summary = '' %}
{% for i in 1..(paragraphs|length) %}
    {% set summary = summary ~ paragraphs[i] %}
    {% if summary|length > 300 %}
        {% set shortsummary = summary %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set final_summary = shortsummary|slice(:300) ~ '[Read More]' %}
```

**EDIT #3 Code modified with the solution to the problem**

```
{% set paragraphs = new.description|striptags|truncate(300,true)|raw|nl2br %}

{% set paragraphs = paragraphs|split('<br />') %}

{% set summary = "" %}
{% set cont = 90 %}
{% set type = "" %}

{% if paragraphs|length == 1 %}
   {% set summary =  paragraphs[0] %}
   {% if summary|length <= 300 %}
      {% set type = "" %}
   {% else %}
      {% set type = "anything" %}
   {% endif %}
{% else %}
   {% for i in 1..(paragraphs|length) %}
      {% if summary|length + cont + paragraphs[i-1]|length  <= 500 %}
          {% set summary = summary  ~ "<br>" ~ paragraphs[i-1] %}
          {% set cont = cont + 90 %}
      {% else %}
          {% set type = "anything" %}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

//In the case of a description with less than 300 characters the option "Read More" is not shown
{% if type != "" %}
  <p>{{ summary|striptags|truncate(300,true)|raw|nl2br }}<a class="href_blue" href="{{ path('new', {'id': new.id}) }}"> <strong> [Read More] </strong></a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>{{ summary|striptags|truncate(300,true)|raw|nl2br }}<a class="href_blue" href="{{ path('new', {'id': new.id}) }}"></a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But in this case the content would appear all together without line breaks, and I want to show the text as it was saved (that was already achieved without using the filter "nl2br"). What I must add is the number of characters of each content in each <p>, and for each iteration add that variable for example 70 characters plus it would be the characters that an entire line fills in the container. And also in each iteration should be checked if the variable is greater than 300 for example, so that when it passes no more content is displayed and "Read More"

Comment: Thank you @AlvinBunk, thanks to your help I have modified your code and I solved my problem. I have edited the above code to show the solution. Thank you very much.